# Split constantly on the last delimiter in C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, delimiter

I have the following string:

```
string x = "hello;there;;you;;;!;"
```

The result I want is a list of length four with the following substrings:

```
"hello"
"there;"
"you;;"
"!"
```

In other words, how do I split on the last occurrence when the delimiter is repeating multiple times? Thanks.

Comment: [StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: use a dedicated delimited parser, such as TextFieldParser. Then make an attempt, post your code, and explain where you ran into trouble.

Comment: `x.Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`

Comment: [`Regex.Split(str, @";(?!;)")`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3b%28%3f!%3b%29&i=hello%3bthere%3b%3byou%3b%3b%3b!%3b).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a regex based split:

```
var s = "hello;there;;you;;;!;";
var res = Regex.Split(s, @";(?!;)").Where(m => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(m));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", res));
// => hello, there;, you;;, !
```

See the [C# demo](http://ideone.com/EY3viQ)

The [`;(?!;)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3b%28%3f!%3b%29&i=hello%3bthere%3b%3byou%3b%3b%3b!%3b) regex matches any `;` that is not followed with `;`.

To also avoid matching a `;` at the end of the string (and thus keep it attached to the last item in the resulting list) use [`;(?!;|$)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3b%28%3f!%3b%7c%24%29&i=hello%3bthere%3b%3byou%3b%3b%3b!%3b) where `$` matches the end of string (can be replaced with `\z` if the very end of the string should be checked for).

Comment: Is the `.TrimEnd()` correct? If the string was `"a;b;;"`, I'd expect the result to be `"a", "b;"`. With the `.TrimEnd()` that last `;` would be gone.

Comment: Ok, then you will have to discard the empty matches, see my edit. The outout for `"a;b;;"` is `a, b;`

Comment: This answer is perfect. But what if I want to keep the last semicolon?

Comment: Then use [`;(?!;|$)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3b%28%3f!%3b%7c%24%29&i=hello%3bthere%3b%3byou%3b%3b%3b!%3b) to also avoid matching a `;` at the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you don't want to remove empty entries but keep the separators.

You can use this code:

```
string s = "hello;there;;you;;;!;";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(s, @"(.+?);(?!;)");

foreach(Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Captures[0].Value);
}
```

Comment: It just didn't need to the "(.+?)" part.

Answer (score -1):

```
string x = "hello;there;;you;;;!;"
var splitted = x.Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptryEntries);

foreach (var s in splitted)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", s);
```